# let Path.register() register a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to choose, which File-System-Event I want to get(ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY and/or ENTRY_DELETE). Is it possible to save the events in an `ArrayList<WatchEvent.Kind>` and to register all the events in this ArrayList with the path?
My idea was like:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE;
...
ArrayList<WatchEvent.Kind> eventList;
...
addEvent(ENTRY_MODIFY);
addEvent(ENTRY_CREATE);
...
for (WatchEvent.Kind<?> event : eventList) {
        key = dir.register(watcher, event);
    }
...
public void addEvent(WatchEvent.Kind event) {
    eventList.add(event);

}
```

This seems to register only the last one, in my example the `ENTRY_DELETE` to the File-System. How can I register all of them, so that I can add the events I want to register with the `addEvent()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by my myself, it is pretty simple. 
Just create an ArrayList, add all the Events you want to add and make an Array out of the list. It can be done like this:

```
ArrayList<WatchEvent.Kind> eventList = new ArrayList<>();
eventList.add(StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
WatchEvent.Kind[] eventArray = eventList.toArray(new WatchEvent.Kind[eventList.size()]);
key = dir.register(watcher, eventArray);
```

It is important, that no element is `null` in the Array.